# Index array columns using vectors in GNU Octave/MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

While coding in GNU Octave/MATLAB I came through this simple problem I couldn't figure out by myself: I'm trying to select some elements of a matrix by using some *indexes* stored in an array. Let me put it clear with an example:

Given:

```
A = zeros(5, 3)

0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
0   0   0
```

I would like to select some elements in A matrix row-wise, by using the values in the auxiliary array B as subindices.

Ie. the following B array

```
B = [ 1 3 2 1 3 ]'

1
3
2
1
3
```

should be read as:

```
1 -> index '1' on first row  (element [1, 1])
3 -> index '3' on second row (element [2, 3])
2 -> index '2' on third row  (element [3, 2])
1 -> index '1' on fourth row (element [4, 1])
3 -> index '3' on fifth row  (element [5, 3])
```

Therefore, if we assign value '1' to the elements selected using the aforementioned criteria, the resulting matrix would be:

```
1   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
0   0   1
```

I believe this is a simple operation and I'm convinced that there must be a way to achieve the described behaviour without having to loop across the rows in matrix A.

Thank you.

Edit: Rewrite question so that it is (hopefully) less confusing.

Comment: Those indices are wrong, indeed! How is Matlab supposed to know if 3 means 3 from the first row or the third. Index them as A(1:5,B) and it may work

Comment: The question is confused, could you please rewrite or delete it?

Comment: @smci I've done my best, feel free to edit it further if you still find it confusing.

Comment: Ah you mean sparse- to dense-matrix conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You're saying you want to select the elements in A by using the values in the vector B as column indexes, but your example sets (not gets) new values in matrix A. I'm explaining both cases.

Consider this matrix

```
A = magic(5)

17   24    1    8   15
23    5    7   14   16
 4    6   13   20   22
10   12   19   21    3
11   18   25    2    9
```

Say you want to get/set the diagonal elements of A.

Index pairs in that case are [1,1], [2,2], [3,3], [4,4] and [5,5].

To access elements as a vector, run this

```
A(sub2ind([5,5], (1:5)',(1:5)'))

17
 5
13
21
 9
```

To set elements run this

```
A(sub2ind([5,5], (1:5)',(1:5)')) = 0

 0   24    1    8   15
23    0    7   14   16
 4    6    0   20   22
10   12   19    0    3
11   18   25    2    0
```

These commands can be written as

```
r = 1:5
c = 1:5
A(sub2ind([max(r),max(c)], r',c'))
# to assign values
A(sub2ind([max(r),max(c)], r',c')) = 0
# and to assign different value to each index pair
A(sub2ind([max(r),max(c)], r',c')) = [20 10 50 12 99]
```

In your example,

```
r = 1:5
c = B'
A(sub2ind([max(r),max(c)], r',c')) = 1
# or simply A(sub2ind([max(r),max(B)], r',B)) = 1

1   0   0
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
0   0   1
```

You can read how `sub2ind` works [here](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html).

Comment: My question was a bit confusing indeed. I should have asked for 'getting/setting' the elements instead of 'selecting'. This solution was very explicative and solved my problem perfectly, thanks a lot.  Finally I would like to say that the expression`A(sub2ind([max(r),max(c)], r',c'))` should perhaps be `A(sub2ind(size(A), r',c'))` instead or at least something like `A(sub2ind([size(A, 1) ,max(c)], r',c'))`. Otherwise, if `r` doesn't contain an index refering to the last row, the indices calculated by `sub2ind` won't be correct (because of how GNU Octave/MATLAB linear indexing is done).